# Automated way to convert nested numbered list in Word to a structured Excel file

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

I have the exact opposite question to [Is it possible to convert MCQs on excel into Word?](https://superuser.com/questions/1213047/is-it-possible-to-convert-mcqs-on-excel-into-word?newreg=7ebac02a902143838e91cfc23682ce41)

**Context**

I have a (500 pages) word document structured as follows (it comes from LaTeX via pandoc).

[image]

As you can notice, greek letters in the text are embedded into ultra simple word equation.

I need to convert it to an Excel format where each question would be in column A and answers would follow on the same line as below.

Since my structure is always One question / Four answers I thought of converting the word document to a table with 5 columns and paste special the result in unicode (to conserve greek letters) in Excel.

**My question**

Do you have a more automated way to reach the result below ?

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Converted documents are always tricky. They do not necessarily work the way native Word documents do. In addition there are several ways Word could produce numbering like you show. I think to have any hope of getting meaningful help you will need to post a link to a sample document on OneDrive or DropBox.

Comment: try.. copy 1 page from word, paste in notepad++ , then select all in notepad++,  copy and paste into excel.. will you have a 1 row per line in the excel? does the greek letter appears as expected ? If it does.. it is just another few step to re-arrange it.